# WebView video compatibility for Android versions

Tags: android, video, android-webview

Following code is used to play embedded youtube videos, on a sample app.
The embedded videos play fine in android version 19, 20 etc., but DO NOT play on device of version 10.

My question is two-fold:

a. How do we find the solution (except asking someone of-course ) ? 
   Javadocs do not have info. about this.

b. How do we solve this problem ?

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    //webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://youtu.be/7uq-s0dMLsE");
```

Thanks for all the help in advance !!

Comment: video format does depends on devices too ..to me more specfic u need to see  device specification for video formats

Comment: try this <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>

Comment: Thanks guys ! 
followup questions - how do we check the video compatiblity of a device ? 
Also - hardwareAccelerated="true" is already set and seems to be working for the android version 19/ 20 etc.